# change library path when building rabbitmq

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm building rabbitmq-c for ARM. I exported the library by running :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_library_folder
```

but I'm still getting this error. Somehow, cmake does not find it.

```
$ cmake --build . --target install
Linking C shared library librabbitmq.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [librabbitmq/librabbitmq.so.1.1.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is for runtime: it tells the OS where to look for libraries needed by an executable.

To set the build-time search path you need a CMake directive:

```
SET(LINK_DIRECTORIES path_to_library_folder)
```

However, it looks like there's another issue here.  The library that is being found instead is for your host architecture, not your target architecture, and it's in a standard location.  This leads me to suspect that your cross-compiling config is not set up quite correctly.

Comment: I tried with that too but it doesn't work. I think it's calling the right compiler, otherwise it would recognize the x86 version of libssl isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely it's calling the right compiler.  But there's more to the cross-compile than the compiler